# One-directional database replication without delete on target database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

I have two databases: A small one where data is permanently added and a big one where the data is copied from the small one and is supposed to be stored long term. The small database deletes old data if the database is growing to big. But the big database is supposed to keep this data (that's its purpose).

Is there a way to achieve this by transactional replication?

(I'm not interested in a SQL-Statement solution and regularly calling a job. I know how to do that.)

I've read some stuff about one-directional replication, snapshot replication, transactional replication, and merge replication but I can't figure out if one of those can do what I need. The scenario is not that exotic, isn't it?

I just need someone to point me the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can choose to not replicate delete statement.
Try this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, also @MichaelW. notice you can have it "Call <stored procedure>" too if you wanted to do a "soft-delete" aka flag the records as deleted without actually deleting them, or insert into a log table to maintain what was deleted without actually deleting them, in the destination database.